# Bundle Identifier Changed Core Data Lost

Tags: swift, core-data, bundle-identifier

I changed a project from Objective-C to Swift and created a whole new project when I did this.  I have an app in the AppStore and wanted to send an update instead of releasing a new app.

I understand that my Bundle Identifier needs to be the same when updating an app.  When preparing the app for release, I changed my Bundle Identifier to match my app in the AppStore - since I started with a new project - and in the process my Core Data file seems to be missing.  If I change my Bundle Identifier how do I keep access to Core Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out but here is how I fixed the issue.

1. Change your product name under Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name to the desired product name.  This will change you Bundle Identifier to the desired name.

[image]

[image]

2. Clean your project by selecting Product -> Clean.
3. Select your CoreData model in the project navigator and then select the "Data Model Inspector" in the Inspector tab.  Change the project name under class to the new class name.  I got stuck here since I did not know Spaces, dashes, . are all replaced by underscores.  You can see that my Product Name is FLO-Cycling and the CoreData class is FLO_Cycling.

[image]

[image]

4. If you have imported the Swift bridging header file anywhere make sure to update it.

[image]

I hope this can help someone.

Take care,

Jon

Comment: Didn't work for me. Also, Xcode keeps removing the period in the class name.

Comment: You should use an underscore to replace the period.